# Do extended & director's cut versions get released in theatres?

Tags: distribution, alternate-version

Do [extended & director's cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director's_cut) versions get released in theatres?

Comment: I would think this depends too much on the film and even on the theater.... We have a local theater that screens them occasionally.

Comment: Sometimes (typically for budetary reasons) these extended editions are created on video, such that a high-res version simply doesn't exist. This precludes a theatrical release, or even an HD broadcast. Off the top of my head, the extended edition of *Independence Day* and the director's cuts of *Scream* and *Star Trek:  The Motion Picture* were created this way, and that's at least part of the reason why the Blu-ray releases of those movies contain only the theatrical versions. The extended edition would have to be re-created from scratch for a higher-quality release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes yes but they tend to be short or single runs in more 'art-house' cinemas or as part of a collection of director/actor movies ran together. I saw a 'Blade Runner' thing like this as part of a Ridley Scott appreciation thing a few years ago.

Comment: We also saw the redone Star Wars Ep 4/5/6 re-released in theaters as well.

Comment: Yeah, we got all 12 or whatever hours of the Lord of the Rings director's cuts.

Answer (score 2):

The only sensible answer is "sometimes".

Where movies are particularly popular or well received then studios sometimes release special versions to extend the cinema run (knowing that the extra expense is worth it).

For example, David Fincher's dark nightmare *Seven* which is particularly notable for its very dark (or chiaroscuro) cinematography proved popular enough to sustain a special edition release for cinemas on a contrast-enhancing film process that emphasised the effect of the dark scenes.

*The Lord of the Rings* trilogy also released the (even better) longer versions of the movies in cinemas but only after the success of the (already very long) originals had been established.

And various *Blade Runner* special editions were eventually released in cinemas but long after the original, not very successful, cinema release and only when the movie had proved a cult hit on video demonstrating that there was an audience for Ridley Scott's original version (the original release to cinemas was somewhat altered by the studio).